# automatically adjust the size of a minipage

Tags: latex

I'm trying to get a way to automatically adjust the size of a minipage.

I am creating a report which will have several "paragraphs" that have a floating image on the left and some text on the right of that image and eventually below it if there is enough text. The both of them ( image + text ) make together a "semantic block".

First I did that :

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.15\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{image}\\
    \emph{image caption with no "figure1"}
\end{wrapfigure}
Text related to this image\\
Text related to this image\\
Text not related to this image\\
```

and of course the text not related to the image was considered like the other lines of text, printing on the right of the image.

So i tried to wrap it all :

```
\begin{minipage}[c][10cm]{20cm}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.15\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{image}\\
    \emph{image caption with no "figure1"}
\end{wrapfigure}
Text related to this image\\
Text related to this image\\
\end{minipage}
Text not related to this image\\
```

but it really isn't convenient and the height is fixed.

If there is a better way to do it not using minipage that would be great too.
In the end i plan to make it into a \newenvironment taking 2 parameters : image name and text so I can use it easily in the article.

EDIT: fixed a typo in 2nd code